# how to evaluate Mutual Fund with overall return including Exp Ratio?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds

I am trying to learn how to choose mutual funds for **long-term investment**. My goal is to max the return.

Fund A is simple. Exp Ratio is lower.

Fund B has more restrictions. The Average Annual Returns are much better than A but its Exp Ratio is also much higher than Fund A. Its **Load is waived at Fidelity**.

**Can I say Fund B is better than Fund A based on their numbers?**

Are there any other things I need to consider in the process of evaluation?

Another question: Fund B has a "Redemption Fee Time Reduction" rule. I cannot find detail about how long the Redemption Fee will be reduced to 0. Could anybody give me an estimated number? 3 months, 6 months, ...?

[image]

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

[image]